# Combining QPainter and QTextDocument on QPdfWriter

Tags: python, qpainter, pyside6, qtextdocument

In another question, I learned about `QTextDocument`, and I [was told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736109/create-a-link-with-qpdfwriter/68736474#comment121495082_68736474) that you can use a `QPainter` and a `QTextDocument` on the same page of a PDF. However, when I tried to do that, they each restart the document, wiping out the other's content.

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QPdfWriter, QPainter, QPageSize, QTextDocument, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    pdf = QPdfWriter('example.pdf')
    pdf.setPageSize(QPageSize.Letter)

    # Whichever of these goes second, overwrites the first.
    draw_diagram(pdf)
    print_document(pdf)

    app.exit(0)


def draw_diagram(pdf: QPdfWriter):
    painter = QPainter(pdf)
    painter.drawArc(painter.window().width()//4,
                    painter.window().height()//2 - painter.window().width()//4,
                    painter.window().width()//2,
                    painter.window().width()//2,
                    0,
                    5760)
    painter.drawText(0,
                     painter.window().height()//2,
                     painter.window().width(),
                     painter.window().height()//10,
                     Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop,
                     'https://donkirkby.github.io')
    print(pdf.newPage())
    painter.drawText(painter.window().width()//2,
                     painter.window().height()//2,
                     'Bar')
    print(pdf.newPage())
    painter.end()


def print_document(pdf: QPdfWriter):
    html = "<a href='https://donkirkby.github.io'>donkirkby.github.io</a>"

    document = QTextDocument()
    document.setHtml(html)
    document.print_(pdf)


main()
```

Ideally, I'd like text and drawing on the same page, but this code tries to keep them separate so they don't overwrite each other. It doesn't work either way.

How can I combine drawings with a text document? Is `QTextCursor` helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time a QPainter is set then the QPdfWriter is reset. A possible solution is to use the same QPainter and instead of the print method you should use drawContents, you will also have to handle the paging manually.

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QPdfWriter, QPainter, QPageSize, QTextDocument, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    pdf = QPdfWriter("example.pdf")
    pdf.setPageSize(QPageSize.Letter)

    painter = QPainter(pdf)

    draw_diagram(painter, pdf)
    print_document(painter, pdf)

    painter.end()


def draw_diagram(painter: QPainter, pdf: QPdfWriter):
    painter.drawArc(
        painter.window().width() // 4,
        painter.window().height() // 2 - painter.window().width() // 4,
        painter.window().width() // 2,
        painter.window().width() // 2,
        0,
        5760,
    )
    painter.drawText(
        0,
        painter.window().height() // 2,
        painter.window().width(),
        painter.window().height() // 10,
        Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop,
        "https://donkirkby.github.io",
    )
    print(pdf.newPage())
    painter.drawText(
        painter.window().width() // 2, painter.window().height() // 2, "Bar"
    )
    print(pdf.newPage())


def print_document(painter: QPainter, pdf: QPdfWriter):
    document = QTextDocument()
    document.documentLayout().setPaintDevice(pdf)

    html = "<a href='https://donkirkby.github.io'>donkirkby.github.io</a>"
    document.setHtml(html)

    document.drawContents(painter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I ended up using [eyllanesc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793766/4794) of switching from `document.print_()` to `document.drawContents()`, I also experimented with `QTextCursor` and `QPyTextObject`. This [TextObject example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_widgets_richtext_textobject.html) gives a good introduction. It would be useful if I needed to spread over multiple pages, I think.

Here's my example from the question converted to use `QPyTextObject`:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QSizeF, QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import (QPdfWriter, QPainter, QPageSize, QTextDocument, Qt, QPyTextObject, QTextFormat, QTextCursor,
                           QTextCharFormat)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

DIAGRAM_TEXT_FORMAT = QTextFormat.UserObject + 1
DIAGRAM_DATA = 1
OBJECT_REPLACEMENT = chr(0xfffc)


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    pdf = QPdfWriter('example.pdf')
    pdf.setPageSize(QPageSize.Letter)

    print_document(pdf)

    app.exit(0)


class Diagram(QPyTextObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyShadowingBuiltins
    def intrinsicSize(self,
                      doc: QTextDocument,
                      posInDocument: int,
                      format: QTextFormat) -> QSizeF:
        diameter = doc.textWidth()/4
        return QSizeF(doc.textWidth(), diameter)

    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyShadowingBuiltins
    def drawObject(self,
                   painter: QPainter,
                   rect: QRectF,
                   doc: QTextDocument,
                   posInDocument: int,
                   format: QTextFormat):
        diameter = rect.height()
        message = format.property(DIAGRAM_DATA)
        painter.drawArc((rect.width() - diameter) // 2,
                        rect.y(),
                        diameter,
                        diameter,
                        0,
                        5760)
        painter.drawText(rect,
                         Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter,
                         message)


def print_document(pdf: QPdfWriter):
    html = """\
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum
<a href='https://donkirkby.github.io'>donkirkby.github.io</a>
dolores sit amet.</p>
"""

    document = QTextDocument()
    document.setPageSize(QSizeF(pdf.width(), pdf.height()))
    font = document.defaultFont()
    font.setPixelSize(pdf.height()//60)
    document.setDefaultFont(font)
    diagram_handler = Diagram()
    doc_layout = document.documentLayout()
    doc_layout.registerHandler(DIAGRAM_TEXT_FORMAT, diagram_handler)

    document.setHtml(html)
    cursor = QTextCursor(document)
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
    cursor.insertText('\n')
    
    diagram_format = QTextCharFormat()
    diagram_format.setObjectType(DIAGRAM_TEXT_FORMAT)

    for i in range(1, 11):
        cursor.insertHtml(f'<h3>Heading {i}</h3>')
        cursor.insertText('\n')
        diagram_format.setProperty(DIAGRAM_DATA, f'Message {i} in a circle')
        cursor.insertText(OBJECT_REPLACEMENT, diagram_format)

    document.print_(pdf)


main()
```

The thing I still don't like about this approach is that a page break can be added between the heading and the diagram. I'll ask a follow up question about that.